# Normality of towers of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If I have a tower of fields $F \subseteq E \subseteq K$ and K is finite and normal over F. I know that E needn't be normal over F because for example $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6, \sqrt{2})$ is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$ since it splits $f(x)= x^{6}-8$ but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ doesn't.

My question is: is K normal over E?

Comment: When we are discussing finite extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$, normal over $L$ = splitting field of a polynomial in $L[x]$. So you know that $K$ is the splitting field of a polynomial in $F[x]$. But that polynomial is also in $E[x]$, so...

Comment: Wow...that was beyond silly. Thanks